# Proof of Field Embedding which does not restrict identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $b$ is algebraic over $F$, not in $F$, and lies in some algebraic closure $A$ of $F$. Show that there exists an embedding, $\varphi :F(b)\to A$ for which $\varphi(b)\neq b$.

Would anyone know how to begin to tackle this problem/solve it?

EDIT: All fields assumed to have characteristic 0.

Comment: Embedding in what?

Comment: Not only does the question need clarification, but if the extension is not separable (e.g., if $b={\root p \of X}$ and the base field is $\mathbb F_p$ for prime $p$, then there is a unique map to an algebraic closure of the base field.

Comment: $\mathbb F_p$ is not sufficient as the base field, since it is closed under taking $p$-th roots. You have to take something like $\mathbb F_p(X)$.

Comment: This question is taken from Serge Lang's Undergraduate Algebra so I too am surprised that the question is so ambiguous. I believe the embedding is F(b) into A

Comment: I believe the question is asking for an embedding e: F(b) arrow A, which resticts all of F that is e(F)=F. Also e(b) must not equal b.

Comment: For example, if b=sqrt(2) and F = field of rationals and A = complex numbers, then an embedding e: Q(sqrt(2)) arrow C, for example could be e(a+bsqrt(2)) mapped to (a+bisqrt(2)). This embedding restricts F in that e(F)=F and also is not the identity on sqrt(2) as e(sqrt(2))=isqrt(2) and obviously sqrt(2) does not equal isqrt(2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 3rd edition of Lang's book, this is exercise 2 from section VII.§2, at page 274. Notice that at the beginning of this problem set it is explicitly stated that **all fields are assumed to have characteristic $0$**.

If $b$ is algebraic over $F$ then let $f \in F[X]$ be its minimal polynomial. If $b$ is the only root of $f$ in $A$, then $f = (X-b)^m$ for some $m \ge 1$, i.e. $f = X^m -mb X^{m-1} + \dots$ . Since $f \in F[X]$, it follows that $-mb \in F$, and by dividing by $-m$ (we may do it since $F$ has characteristic $0$) we get $b \in F$, which is forbidden by the hypothesis - which shows that $f$ has at least one other root $c \ne b$ in $A$ (a Galois conjugate of $b$). Notice that $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $c$, too.

Since $b$ is algebraic over $F$, it is known that $F(b) = F[b]$; if $n = [F(b) : F]$, then every element of $F(b)$ is of the form $\sum _{i=0} ^{n-1} a_i b^i$. Define then the morphism $\phi : F(b) = F[b] \to A$ by $\phi (1) = 1$ and $\phi(b) = c$, extended by multiplicativity and additivity, i.e. $\phi (\sum _{i=0} ^{n-1} a_i b^i) = \sum _{i=0} ^{n-1} a_i c^i$.

By construction, $\phi$ is a field morphism with $\phi(b) = c \ne b$. Since $\phi(1) = 1$ by construction, it follows that $\phi$ is injective, therefore an embedding.

---

Just for the fun of it, here is another proof of the injectivity of $\phi$. Notice that $\phi (\sum _{i=0} ^{n-1} a_i b^i) = 0$ is equivalent to $\sum _{i=0} ^{n-1} a_i c^i = 0$, so $c$ is a root of $\sum _{i=0} ^{n-1} a_i X^i \in F[X]$. Since $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $c$, it follows that $f \mid \sum _{i=0} ^{n-1} a_i X^i$. Since $b$ is a root of $f$, it follows that $b$ will also be a root of $\sum _{i=0} ^{n-1} a_i X^i$, i.e. $\sum _{i=0} ^{n-1} a_i b^i = 0$, showing that $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: A field morphism with $\phi(1) =1$ is always injective and so the last part wasn't necessary ;)

Comment: @Max: Thank you for telling that to me, I wasn't aware of it (not a field theory specialist). I am not going to remove that part though, your comment will enlighten future readers.

Comment: the proof of it is very simple : consider any $x\in Ker\phi \setminus \{0\}$, and then $\phi(xx^{-1}) = \phi(1) =1 $, but also $\phi(xx^{-1}) =\phi(x)\phi(x^{-1}) = 0$ since $\phi(x)=0$ by assumption, which is a contradiction, so $Ker\phi = \{0\}$, and $\phi$ is injective. (But indeed, there is no need for you to remove that part)

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you very much for your answer, which was both easy to follow and precise